# What is the name of module scope? How to refer to this scope?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

We have a global object in javascript that we can refer to using `window` for accessing any global variable. But how to refer to the module scope object where all the variables in that module are stored?

Actually, I need to refer to an imported object in the module using string. If it was a global variable, I could've simply done this,

```
let object_I_want = window[string];
```

But for module, I can't find the reference for such object. I also tried using `this`,

```
var scope = this;

somefunction(){
   let object_I_want = scope[string];
}
```

But, `this` is undefined inside module context according to the specification. Is there a way to reference the module scope/module object like `window`.

Comment: No, the global object is part of the global environment. Module environments do not have an object that contain its var declarations.

Comment: Have you tried [`globalThis`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)?

Comment: What would you need this for?

Comment: I was looking for this in the context of making hot-reloading modules easier/cleaner by using the equivalent of ``Object.defineProperty(window, `SomeClassName`, { get: () => { ... }}``. instead of needing `import { SomeClassName as n } from "somewhere.js"; let SomeClassName = n; watchFileChange("somewhere.js", lib => (SomeClassName = lib.SomeClassName))`. And while that's _pretty_ niche, would have cleaned up a lot of code if there was a module-level equivalent of `window` or `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such object for modules. The module scope is like a function scope - an environment record that you cannot access from javascript, you can only use it to declare variables.

There is an object that holds all the `export`ed names of a module (which you can get by doing a namespace `import * as … from …`), but this doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have other ways to do what I want in my code but I just wanted to know if it was possible to access the variables in such way.

Answer (score 2):

I think another way to word your question might be: "How can I access scoped variables using strings?", and the answer is "It's not possible in JavaScript".

If you truly need this kind of dynamic flexibility with your values, you must assign them all to a top-level object (and you must export that object from your module if you want to access it and its values outside the module). Or use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), if supported in your environment.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to access them inside the module itself. But as I want to reference them using strings, I wanted to learn if I can access them using something simple like `window[string]`. Later I just stored all the imported variables in an object and referenced them using `obj[string]`